# How can I determine the page count of odt, doc, docx and other office documents from the CLI?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, pdf, microsoft-office, djvu

It's easy to find the page count of a PDF document from the command line:

```
pdfinfo sample.pdf | grep ^Pages:
```

... but I haven't been able to find a similar method for `odt` files and other office documents.

Is there a way to programmatically determine the page count of these documents?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, everyone. With your help I was able to compile a list of commands that can extract the page count from almost all relevant office documents:

**DOCX/PPTX**

```
unzip -p 'sample.docx' docProps/app.xml | grep -oP '(?<=\<Pages\>).*(?=\</Pages\>)'

unzip -p 'sample.pptx' docProps/app.xml | grep -oP '(?<=\<Slides\>).*(?=\</Slides\>)'
```

*Note*: `unzip` can be installed with `sudo apt-get install unzip`.

**DOC/PPT**

```
wvSummary sample.doc | grep -oP '(?<=of Pages = )[ A-Za-z0-9]*'

wvSummary sample.ppt | grep -oP '(?<=of Slides = )[ A-Za-z0-9]*'
```

*Note*: `wvSummary` (case-sensitive!) is part of the `wv` package. Install it with `sudo apt-get install wv`.

**ODT**

```
unzip -p sample.odt meta.xml | grep -oP '(?<=page-count=")[ A-Za-z0-9]*'
```

**PDF**

```
pdfinfo sample.pdf | grep -oP '(?<=Pages:          )[ A-Za-z0-9]*'
```

Note: `pdfinfo` is part of `poppler-utils` and should come preinstalled on Ubuntu.

**DJVU**

```
djvused -e "n" sample.djvu
```

Note: `djvused` is part of the `djvulibre-bin` package and may be installed with `sudo apt-get install djvulibre-bin`.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find a way to extract `odt` file info as `pdfinfo` does, but you can create a fast script to use `pdfinfo` with the `odt` files, converting each odt file to PDF and later deleting the converted file if you are not going to use it:

```
libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf sample.odt
pdfinfo sample.pdf | grep ^Pages:
rm sample.pdf
```

Hope that this helped you.

Answer (score 6):

```
unzip -p document.odt meta.xml | grep -o 'page-count="[0-9]*"'
```

[See here for more reference](http://plugfest.opendocsociety.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=plugfests:201210_berlin%3alibreoffice-fho-20121017.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the link! that was a very interesting read. I would have accepted your answer but I found a few other nifty commands for other office docs and compiled them in an answer of my own. I hope you don't mind.